# Wordpress Shortcode inside of plugin

Tags: php, css, wordpress, shortcode

Here is a snippet from the shortcodes.php file in one of the plugins I'm writing.

```
if($home_loop->have_posts()) {
        switch($display) {      

        case "static":

                while ($home_loop->have_posts()): $home_loop->the_post();

                        if(has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                            $content .= '<div class="parallax">';
                            $content .= get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'wrapper-wide', array('class' => "img-responsive")); 
                            $content .= '</div>';
                            $content .= '<div class="container">';
                            $content .= get_the_content();
                            $content .= '</div>';

                            $content .= '<style>';
                            $content .= '.parallax{//css style here}';

                            $content .= '</style>;



                        } else {
                            //Something
                        }

                endwhile;

                break;
```

This works perfect. If I put a featured image thumbnail in my home post it will be displayed in my parallax div. The question I have is instead of placing the thumbnail inside of the div, I want to have it background-image: url(). I found this code below

```
<?php
$background = get_field( 'background_image' );

if($background):
?>
<style>
.main-wrapper {
 background-image: url(<?php echo $background ?>);
}
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How would I incorporate and run something like this inside of the $content? The reason I'm trying to get the image as a background-image:url() is so I can add specific css styling like background-position, size, repeat, attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add the image as a background-image right inside your code? [wp_get_attachment_image_src][1] will return an array of the url, width and height of any attachment.  Pass it the ID of the featured image, and gain the flexibility to use ANY size you want, not just the actual featured image size.  Then place it as the background using inline CSS.  It can be overwritten in your CSS sheet if needed.

```
($home_loop->have_posts()) {
        switch($display) {      

        case "static":

                while ($home_loop->have_posts()): $home_loop->the_post();

                        if(has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            $post_thumnail_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'wrapper-wide' );
                            $content .= '<div class="parallax" style="background-image: url( \'' . $post_thumbnail_info[0] . '\' );">';
```

Comment: - thanks for the reply! I didn't know about the wp_get_attachment_image_src .. When I use the code you sent me.. It's not retrieving the image. When I inspect the element Im getting background-image: url(;

Comment: You  might need to do one of two things... change the 'post-thumbnail' to reflect an actual image size you have... try the default 'large', 'medium', 'thumbnail' to see if it changes... The other thing you might need to alter is to remove $post->id from the get_post_thumbnail_id() function call.  Let me know if any of those fix it, and I'll update my answer to reflect the changes

Comment: Thank you, I went ahead and changed the post-thumbnail to one I created that didn't work so I used the default one 'large' that didn't work. I tried removing $post->id, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump on $post_thumbnail_info and tell me what you are getting?

Comment: I updated my code for you again... it appears I should have used single quotes on the url() piece, so I added those.  The \ are to escape them from PHP thinking it's the end of the string.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: And I assumed you are using 'wrapper-wide' as your image size name... if not, change that to whatever image size you have available...

Comment: Thank you so much, initially the code didn't work but I just changed the variable names and it worked. Thank you! Ill be sure to put as best answer